# implicit and explicit conversion

Tags: c#, list, object

I start a thread like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SetupThread), (object)new object[] { IP, lc });
```

To comit the arguments I used the object. IP is easy to recover, but lc ist a list. How can I acess this argument?

```
    private void SetupThread(object obj)
    {
        object[] arg = obj as object[];
        String IPadress = Convert.ToString(arg[0]);
        List<String> listcom = arg[1];

        theNDDssh.RunListCom(IPadress,
                             listcom,
                                    sshqueue,
                                    error
                            );
```

The Compiler says that there is a explicit conversion. arg[1] can not be converted implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> listcom = (List<string>)arg[1];
```

Its a simple cast. You can do the same with the first argument instead of the Convert call.

Comment: May I add, casts in C# are typically done in this way:

`DataType variableName = (DataType)expression`

Explicit conversion requires use of _casts_, while implicit conversions from Data Type A to Data Type B are _implied_ .

`DataType` is the type of data **to convert to** and the data type **the variable is**. Make sure `DataType` is the same between both spots, otherwise it can't convert.

`variableName` is the name of the variable.

`expression` is the expression you want to _cast_ the result of into `DataType`.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE yes, thats true. It should also be noted that typically in .NET you can implicitly convert between types when there is no chance of a loss of data (float to double) but if there is possible loss of data (double to float) an explicit cast is required. Almost always between object and whatever requires an explicit conversion because the compiler can't infer the type.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a [`Tuple<T,T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SetupThread), Tuple.Create(IP, lc));
```

Cast it back in the target method, and then just access each item inside it:

```
private void SetupThread(object obj)
{
    var args = (Tuple<string, List<string>>)obj;

    String IPadress = args.Item1;
    List<String> listcom = args.Item2;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it as a

```
(List<String>)
```